# Multiple children processes running at the same time

Tags: apache2

I have a lot of issues with my server and I found that is because of these children processes:

```
13461 root       20   0  292M 38824 30800 S  0.0  0.5  0:00.03 ├─ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start


13489 www-data   20   0  292M 15612  7564 S  0.0  0.2  0:00.00 │  ├─ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
13488 www-data   20   0  292M 17852  9688 S  0.0  0.2  0:00.00 │  ├─ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
  13487 www-data   20   0  312M 60584 33804 S  0.7  0.7  0:00.17 │  ├─ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
  13486 www-data   20   0  308M 55608 34236 S  0.0  0.7  0:00.17 │  ├─ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
  13485 www-data   20   0  301M 56820 39172 S  0.0  0.7  0:00.16 │  ├─ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
  13484 www-data   20   0  312M 60252 33276 S  0.0  0.7  0:00.18 │  ├─ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
  13483 www-data   20   0  318M 67240 34044 S  0.7  0.8  0:00.28 │  ├─ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
  13482 www-data   20   0  302M 52836 36108 S  1.3  0.6  0:00.18 │  ├─ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
  13481 www-data   20   0  302M 53172 36240 S  0.0  0.7  0:00.16 │  ├─ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
  13480 www-data   20   0  312M 60484 33732 S  0.7  0.7  0:00.23 │  ├─ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
  13479 www-data   20   0  304M 60268 40540 S  0.0  0.7  0:00.25 │  ├─ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
  13478 www-data   20   0  306M 72048 50908 S  0.7  0.9  0:00.57 │  ├─ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
  13471 www-data   20   0  318M 68884 36792 S  0.7  0.8  0:00.46 │  ├─ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
  13470 www-data   20   0  322M 74324 36892 S  0.0  0.9  0:00.55 │  ├─ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
  13468 www-data   20   0  330M 92356 49244 S  0.7  1.1  0:00.77 │  ├─ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
  13466 www-data   20   0  304M 55188 36216 S  0.0  0.7  0:00.51 │  ├─ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
  13465 www-data   20   0  330M 93472 50280 S  0.7  1.1  0:00.77 │  ├─ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
  13464 www-data   20   0  334M 83780 36764 S  0.7  1.0  0:00.72 │  ├─ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
  13463 www-data   20   0  308M 67112 43864 R  3.3  0.8  0:00.60 │  ├─ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
  13462 www-data   20   0  309M 71384 47772 S  0.7  0.9  0:00.73 │  └─ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

As you can see, I have my parent process, and then a lot of children processes are spawning and they won´t stop. This is making my server super slow that I can´t even work on it.

**Could you tell me how can I set a limit for these children processes?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those child processes are how Apache works. There are not making your server slow. They actually make your web application faster. Apache processes that are idle/sleeping do not consume CPU resources, only a small amount of memory - most of which is shared memory.  In comparison, most Linux servers have dozens or even hundreds of sleeping processes. Removing the Apache ones will not make your server faster except in isolated cases. If your server is slow, you have a different problem to investigate.

Comment: Actually, it was fault of these processes. I found out that they were generated because one of the computers used by the users was requesting multiple actions at once. It was a malware in the computer who caused all of these by sending too much requests.

Answer (score 0):

This was due to a malware installed in the user's computer, causing a lot of request at once. I cleaned the computer and it stopped sending that amount of request/processes.